# SUM () OVER (Partition By) на MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Гуру MySQL, подскажите, как синтаксически переписать примерно такой запрос, где используется SUM (...) OVER (Partition By...) и ROW_NUMBER() OVER, все єто дело идет как вложенный позапрос.

Пример:

```sql
SELECT ils.QuantityOnHand ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ai.AdjustmentType, 
                                    ai.[LineNo] ) AS [LineNo],
                                    ( ils.QuantityOnHand + SUM(( CASE WHEN ai.AdjustmentType = 2 
                                                                      THEN ai.Quant  * ai.ConvFac
                                                                      WHEN ai.AdjustmentType = 3 
                                                                      THEN -ai.Quant  * ai.ConvFac
                                                                      ELSE ai.Quant  * ai.ConvFac - ils.QuantityOnHand 
                                                                  END 
                                                               )) OVER ( PARTITION BY ai.InvLocPK ) 
                                    ) AS NewOnHand 
FROM      AdjItem  AS ai
JOIN InvLoc AS il ON ai.InvLocPK = il.InvLocPK
JOIN Locs AS loc ON il.LocPK = loc.LocPK
LEFT JOIN InvTrack AS it ON it.InvPK = il.InvPK
                        AND it.FacilityPK = loc.FacilityPK
JOIN InvLocStat AS ils ON il.InvLocPK = ils.InvLocPK
```

Comment: Эмулировать их в отдельных подзапросах, с добавлением полей, которые позволят привязать их в основной запрос.

Comment: Некоторые поля имеют алиас `ils` - но таблицы с таким именем нет. И скобки не согласованы. поправьте текст запроса до корректного состояния.

Comment: Подправил запрос

Comment: Гм... А что делает в источнике данных таблица `InvTrack AS it`?

Comment: Это кусок селекта, там идет набор некоторых полей с таблиц, которые есть в джойнах. Мне нужно хотя бы понять логику с точки зрения синтаксиса, как подобные квесты можно переписать)

Comment: Делаешь запрос, который на основе того же источника данных вычисляет только самую внутреннюю конструкцию (в данном примере SUM(CASE...)), а выражение PARTITION переносишь в GROUP BY. Кроме SUM, в выходном наборе добавляешь все внешние относительно этой конструкции поля. Полученный текст запроса добавляешь как подзапрос (или делаешь view) в источник данных внешней по отношению к нему конструкции, связываешь по необходимым полям, а вместо SUM() OVER () используешь рассчитанное в подзапросе значение. Аналогично поступаешь и с внешним ROW_NUMBER (или используй нумерацию с переменными).

Comment: Вынес отдельно весь запрос, где используется sum() over (partition by), в @table, в group by вынес все поля вместе с partition by, оно выдает датасет в 24 строки, а в оригинале с partition - 162

Comment: Значит, где-то что-то неверно вынес. Но расплетать этот ужас в уме мне лично влом, равно как и создавать модельный fiddle с адекватными тестовыми данными.

Comment: В MS SQL я же могу таким способом через group by сделать аналог sum() over (partition by)?

Comment: Конечно. Используемые при эмуляции конструкции не выходят за рамки "общего для всех" SQL.